# Facebook Sharing Crawler Not showing OG:Description

Tags: facebook, twitter, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

On my website, we have Functionality for dynamically updating Facebook, Twitter, and Linkedin post title, description, and image. Now What happens, sometimes when the user enters a long title in the post it shows the title only and the description is missing. And in Linkedin event title has a length of only 5 characters it still not showing description.
I have tried to debug the post on Facebook sharing debugger and Linkedin's post inspector it's crawling perfectly. is there any length limits for sharing or any rules for omitting the information.

Comment: I’m not aware of any documentation on title length for Facebook, but through some experimentation, it appears (for a large image rich link preview) Facebook will display two lines of text. If the title is > 65 characters, it will wrap to the second line and no description is displayed. For two lines of title, Facebook will show up to around 128 characters (it seems to depend on character width, rather than count). LinkedIn only displays the title (no description). For a small image rich link preview, Facebook will display 5 lines of title and description.

Comment: this info helped me for my problem. thanks Rich.